# Factoring $a^2+b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, factoring

I remember there was a way to factor $a^2+b^2$ into something along the lines of $(a+\sqrt{a}+b)(a-\sqrt{a}+b)$ . I tried every combination of pluses and minuses for this form, but I couldn't get back the original.

Comment: Look up on $a^4 + 4b^4$  Sophie Germain.

Comment: $(a+ib)(a-ib)$ for example, it depends on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have
$$
a^2 + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 - 2ab\\
= (a + b)^2 - 2ab\\
= \big((a + b) +\sqrt{2ab}\big)\big((a + b) - \sqrt{2ab}\big)
$$
This is a trick commonly attributed to Sophie Germain, if memory serves.